# URLEncoder implementation Round 2

Tags: java, performance, memory-optimization

Half an year ago I [posted an implementation of a URL encoder for review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/142428/urlencoder-implementation). I didn't have any time to work on it until recently, but now looking at my old code with new eyes I saw how unreadable the code was.

So here comes my second attempt. The "requirements" are the same:

- no changes to the public API of the [original encoder](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/trunk/java/org/apache/catalina/util/URLEncoder.java):

  - i.e. the class is not final on purpose;
  - the stupid DEFAULT instance is there because it's present in the original encoder;
  - etc.
- doing as little as possible memory allocations without hurting the performance.
- the internal implementation is intentionally hidden so that derived classes do not depend on something that might change any time and also allow for the encoder implementation to evolve and improve over time;

Any remarks, suggestions and ideas for improvement are greatly appreciated. I'm mostly interested in improving the readability of the code

### Here is the code:

```
public class EnhancedUrlEncoder {
    private static final class DefaultEncoderPool extends EnhancedUrlEncoder {
        private final EnhancedUrlEncoder[] encoders;

        public DefaultEncoderPool(int poolSize) {
            super(null);
            encoders = new EnhancedUrlEncoder[poolSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < encoders.length; i++) {
                encoders[i] = new EnhancedUrlEncoder();
                encoders[i].addSafeCharacter('~');
                encoders[i].addSafeCharacter('-');
                encoders[i].addSafeCharacter('_');
                encoders[i].addSafeCharacter('.');
                encoders[i].addSafeCharacter('*');
                encoders[i].addSafeCharacter('/');
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void addSafeCharacter(char c) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Modification of the default encoder is not allowed");
        }

        @Override
        public String encode(String string, String encoding) {
            final long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
            final int index = (int) (threadId % encoders.length);
            return encoders[index].encode(string, encoding);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This constant determines how many characters
     * the encoder can process at once
     */
    private static final int CHAR_BUFFER_SIZE = 16;

    /**
     * The output buffer should be large enough to avoid
     * most overflow conditions when possible. Yet, too
     * large buffer is a waste of space
     */
    private static final int BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE = CHAR_BUFFER_SIZE * 4;

    /**
     * The initial capacity of the newly allocated StringBuilders.
     */
    private static final int INITIAL_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY = 32;

    /**
     * Do not cache StringBuilders with larger capacity because it's a
     * waste of heap space.
     */
    private static final int MAX_CACHEABLE_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY = 256;

    /**
     * Mask for extracting the lower four bits of a byte
     */
    private static final int MASK_LOW = 0x0f;

    /**
     * Mask for extracting the higher four bits of a byte
     */
    private static final int MASK_HIGH = 0xf0;

    /**
     * Each encoded byte must be prefixed with the percent sign
     */
    private static final char PERCENT = '%';

    /**
     * The hexadecimal alphabet
     */
    private static final char[] HEXADECIMAL = {
            '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'
    };

    /**
     * Default instance
     */
    public static final EnhancedUrlEncoder DEFAULT;

    static {
        final int poolSize = Math.min(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors(), 16);
        DEFAULT = new DefaultEncoderPool(poolSize);
    }

    private final BitSet safeCharacters;
    private final ByteBuffer byteBuffer;
    private final CharBuffer charBuffer;
    private final StringBuilder encoded;

    private CharsetEncoder charsetEncoder;
    private boolean endOfUnsafeCharactersSequence;
    private int currentPosition;

    public EnhancedUrlEncoder() {
        safeCharacters = new BitSet(256);
        addAsciiAlphanumericSymbols();

        byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BYTE_BUFFER_SIZE);
        charBuffer = CharBuffer.allocate(CHAR_BUFFER_SIZE);

        assert INITIAL_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY <= MAX_CACHEABLE_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY;
        encoded = new StringBuilder(INITIAL_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY);
    }

    /**
     * Should be used only by the <code>DefaultEncoderPool</code>
     */
    private EnhancedUrlEncoder(Void notUsed) {
        // do not allocate memory for private fields
        this.byteBuffer = null;
        this.charBuffer = null;
        this.safeCharacters = null;
        this.encoded = null;
    }

    private void addAsciiAlphanumericSymbols() {
        for (char i = 'a'; i <= 'z'; i++) {
            addSafeCharacter(i);
        }
        for (char i = 'A'; i <= 'Z'; i++) {
            addSafeCharacter(i);
        }
        for (char i = '0'; i <= '9'; i++) {
            addSafeCharacter(i);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Add character to the set of characters that must not be encoded.
     *
     * @param c the character to add
     */
    public void addSafeCharacter(char c) {
        safeCharacters.set(c);
    }

    public synchronized String encode(String string, String encoding) {
        initializeCharsetEncoderFor(encoding);

        currentPosition = 0;
        while (currentPosition < string.length()) {
            final char character = string.charAt(currentPosition);
            if (safeCharacters.get(character)) {
                encodeSafeCharacter(character);
            } else {
                encodeSequenceOfUnsafeCharacters(string);
            }
        }

        return getEncodedString();
    }

    private void initializeCharsetEncoderFor(String encoding) {
        if (null == charsetEncoder || !charsetEncoder.charset().name().equals(encoding)) {
            final Charset charset = Charset.forName(encoding);
            charsetEncoder = charset.newEncoder();
        }
    }

    private void encodeSafeCharacter(char character) {
        encoded.append(character);
        currentPosition += 1;
    }

    /**
     * Encode a sequence of unsafe characters
     *
     * @param string The string to encode
     */
    private void encodeSequenceOfUnsafeCharacters(String string) {
        /*
         * Reset the buffer and the encoder
         * in case the previous encoding failed
         */
        recycle(charBuffer);
        charsetEncoder.reset();

        for (int charsRead; (charsRead = readChunkOfUnsafeCharactersFrom(string)) > 0; ) {
            charBuffer.flip();

            CoderResult encodingResult;
            do {
                recycle(byteBuffer);

                encodingResult = charsetEncoder.encode(charBuffer, byteBuffer, endOfUnsafeCharactersSequence);
                validateEncodingResult(encodingResult, string, charsRead);

                byteBuffer.flip();
                appendToEncoded(byteBuffer);
            } while (encodingResult.isOverflow());

            /*
             * If the buffer has any remaining unprocessed characters
             * they must be preserved for the next encoding operation.
             */
            charBuffer.compact();
        }

        /*
         * All characters from the source buffer must have been processed
         */
        assert charBuffer.position() == 0;

        flushEncoder();
    }

    /**
     * Read from the source string starting from the current position
     * until either the buffer is filled, end of input or a safe
     * character is reached
     *
     * @param source The string to read from
     * @return number of characters read
     */
    private int readChunkOfUnsafeCharactersFrom(String source) {
        endOfUnsafeCharactersSequence = true;

        final int initialPosition = currentPosition;
        while (currentPosition < source.length()) {
            final char character = source.charAt(currentPosition);
            if (safeCharacters.get(character)) {
                break;
            }

            if (!charBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
                endOfUnsafeCharactersSequence = false;
                break;
            }

            charBuffer.put(character);
            currentPosition += 1;
        }

        return currentPosition - initialPosition;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare debug information in case the encoding failed.
     * Should never happen.
     *
     * @param result    The result of the encoding operation
     * @param source    The string with the original, unencoded message
     * @param charsRead How many new characters were inside the input buffer
     */
    private void validateEncodingResult(CoderResult result, String source, int charsRead) {
        if (result.isError()) {
            final String errorDetails = "\tSource: '" + source + "'" +
                    "\tNext character index: '" + currentPosition + "'" +
                    "\tChars read: '" + charsRead + "'" +
                    "\tEnd of input: '" + endOfUnsafeCharactersSequence + "' " +
                    "\tCoder result: '" + result + "'";

            if (result.isUnmappable()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Non mappable input: " + errorDetails);
            } else if (result.isMalformed()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Malformed input: " + errorDetails);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown coder state: " + errorDetails);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Make sure that everything has been encoded and written to the output buffer
     */
    private void flushEncoder() {
        CoderResult flushResult;
        do {
            recycle(byteBuffer);
            /*
             * According to the javadoc, flush cannot return an error,
             * so no need to call validateEncodingResult()
             */
            flushResult = charsetEncoder.flush(byteBuffer);
            byteBuffer.flip();
            appendToEncoded(byteBuffer);
        } while (flushResult.isOverflow());
    }

    /**
     * Append the encoded chunk to the result.
     * This method does not flip/recycle the buffer
     *
     * @param dataToAppend Buffer containing the encoded data
     */
    private void appendToEncoded(ByteBuffer dataToAppend) {
        while (dataToAppend.hasRemaining()) {
            final byte toEncode = dataToAppend.get();
            encoded.append(PERCENT);

            final int high = (toEncode & MASK_HIGH) >> 4;
            encoded.append(HEXADECIMAL[high]);

            final int low = toEncode & MASK_LOW;
            encoded.append(HEXADECIMAL[low]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recycle the provided buffer - set the limit to the
     * capacity and the position to zero.
     *
     * @param buffer The buffer to recycle
     */
    private void recycle(Buffer buffer) {
        buffer.limit(buffer.capacity());
        buffer.rewind();
    }

    /**
     * Convert the result of the encoding operation to java.lang.String,
     * and downsize the intermediate (cached) StringBuilder if necessary
     */
    private String getEncodedString() {
        final String encodedAsString = encoded.toString();

        if (encoded.capacity() > MAX_CACHEABLE_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY) {
            encoded.setLength(INITIAL_STRING_BUILDER_CAPACITY);
            encoded.trimToSize();
        }

        encoded.setLength(0);
        return encodedAsString;
    }
}
```